# Why does my database not open?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

I am using SQLite in a windows 8.1 mobile app and when I am trying to delete something from the database I get an exception in the method `RunInTransaction`:

```all
Cannot create commands from unopened database.
```

But when I try to insert something it works fine!
This is the insertion method:

```all
// Inserts a new place in the Places table.   
public void InsertPlace(PlacesTable place) {
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH)) {
        dbConn.RunInTransaction(() => {
            dbConn.Insert(place);
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the delete method:

```all
// Deletes all the places from the database.  
public void DeletePlaces() {
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH)) {
        dbConn.RunInTransaction(() => {
            dbConn.DropTable<PlacesTable>();
            dbConn.CreateTable<PlacesTable>();
            dbConn.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
        });
    }
}
```

Why does this exception occur in the second case?

So, I found out that `Dispose` and `Close` were responsible for the exception, though I would like someone to explain me why this happened. 
Was `Close` causing a problem because I had `using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))` and `Dispose` for a similar reason?
I had found this at a tutorial, so it took me some time until I thought that the code had a mistake.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Maybe you should first close and then dispose.

Comment: Somehow, dispose was creating the problem! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not 'somehow'. Actually all objects should ne completely unusable after *Dispose* was called on them.